Formal verification of analytical formulations
I have been curious about one idea recently, which is how to efficiently do some formal verification with an analytical formulation, or say symbolic formulation like f(x)=2x. Specifically, I want to check if an analytical formulation satisfies some properties in the given domain. For example, is f(x) always positive?
For context I know, there are some logic-based verification tools such as Satisfiability modulo theories used a lot in neural networks, but I think there should be some way more elegant. For positiveness, one can check roots, but root finding can be hard when the nonlinear function is difficult. Similarly with optimization-based methods. And I think the root-finding methods and optimization-based methods can fail. It will also be a very good point if anyone can share some developed numerical methods that can guarantee finding a root.
I am wondering if there is any good way to do this kind of verification with guarantees. Thanks! Any discussion is highly appreciated! (I am not sure which tag I should use).
